# css how to align a div to the top of a containing div

Tags: css

Sorry for basic question. I have the following layout:

```
#existing-files .image-row{
  width: 700px;
  border: 1px solid orange;
  padding-left: 10px; 
}

.img-row-description{
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: inline;
  width: 400px;
}
```

And it looks like this:

[image]

I'd like for the .img-row-description to be aligned to the top of the containing image-row. How would I do that?

Comment: Can you add the HTML structure?

Comment: thx j - i thought i had tried that but seems to have done the trick

Comment: @j08691: You should make that an answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: @j08691, post this as a answer. Also, timpone, mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what timpone's markup looks like, but I provided a couple jsFiddles for anyone who would like to explore how to do this.

As long as the structure in the markup is simple and valid, this effect can be accomplished by floating the img left rather than using `vertical-align: top`

Depending upon what you want to do:

[Text wrapping around the image](http://jsfiddle.net/uzDBt/)

[No text wrapping around the image](http://jsfiddle.net/uzDBt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vertical-align:top`